# LoginButton from Facebook SDK is null

Tags: android

I'm using FB SDK and LoginButton is null even if the UI shows it right.

JAVA:

```
loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
```

XML:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
```

GRADLE:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.34.0'
```

Comment: Can you check that the layout you've set in the setContentView() is the one with the button? I often make this mistake.

Comment: This was the problem. The button was inside of one nav_header. To access the object i used `navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. and i hope you add internet permission and other things into android manifest files..

```
/**
 * this method used to user login with facebook.
 */
private void loginWithFacebook() {

    mLoginFbButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email");
    mLoginFbButton.setFragment(this);
    mLoginFbButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {
                        registerUsingFaceBook(profile2);
                    }
                };
            } else {
                registerUsingFaceBook(Profile.getCurrentProfile());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

         }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        }
    });
}
```

more information refer this link..
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Comment: The internet permission is already set up. I've done what you suggesting, but this doesn't have any connection with my problem. If i do this, it will throw `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.setReadPermissions(java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference `

Comment: this permission add into fb devloper option.

Comment: I need to say the button works as expected. (It make connection to my fb acount) Only problem is that i can't  receive the object reference in java...

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean? I don't understand and i'm still trying to figure out what is the problem(in FB analytics it appears that i've connected with app but no java object refernce available)